# Windows Azure Cloud: End user requirements

Tags: .net, silverlight, azure

If I was going to create an application on Windows Azure Cloud, which the end user would access through a web browser. I wonder what the requirements for the end user are in order to use that application?

If I was going to write the frontend in Silverlight, is everything the user would need be just the Silverlight runtime? Or does the user also need the whole .NET 3.5/4.0 runtime as well?

Many Thanks,
Kave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Silverlight runtime is all that the user needs to install. Silverlight is completely independent of the Windows .Net framework.

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows Azure makes no difference.  If you are building Silverlight apps the client needs the Silverlight runtime.